# disable preg_replace() for some images...

Tags: php, wordpress, preg-replace, hook

I am using this function to replace `data-rel` and to add `hyperlink` to images of the content.

```
function add_image_responsive_class($content) {
   global $post;  
   $pattern ="~<img(.*?)class=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)src=\"(.*?)\"(.*?)>~i";
   $replacement = '<a href="$4" data-rel="lightbox-gallery"><img$1class="$2"$3src="$4"$5></a>';
   $content = preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $content);
   return $content;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'add_image_responsive_class');
```

Its working awesome, but there is one issue I am facing now. Some time I want to add images which will have different links. For example I want to add logos which will link to their websites. But they are opening the same image because of my `preg_replace()` function.

Is there any way to disable it for some images somehow? I cant use LINK TO MEDIA FILE for every image, that's why I am using this function. **PLEASE HELP ME!**